# k-means core function for temporal geo data

Tags: k-means, geo, temporal

I want cluster geo data (lat,long,timestamp) with k-means. I'm searching for a good core function, I can't find good paper or other sources for that. To time I multiplicate the time and the space distance:

```
public static double dis(GeoData input1, GeoData input2)
{
   double timeDis = Math.abs( input1.getTime() - input2.getTime() );
   double geoDis = geoDis(input1, input2); //extra function
   return timeDis*geoDis;
}
```

Maybe someone know a good core function for clustering temporal geo data? 
(need citation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of work already done using clustering technique for geo data. Check this paper which explain how to use k-mean and density based clustering in geo-data.

> http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~prodei/dsie12/papers/paper_13.pdf

Important step is we calculate Euclidean distance for 3D space(lat,long,timestamp).

I hope this paper would help you to understand. Please go through it.

Comment: You mean the distance measure in 3.2. The point is the Euclidean distance, I want use the real geo distance plus timestamp. Maybe it give an other formel or someone can transform this given formel.

Comment: yes, I mean distance measure in section 3.2. For my understanding geo data have longitude and latitude which is floating point. Real geo distance consist of (lat,long,timestamp) right? If so it is 3d space still you can calculate distance using d=sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2+(t2-t1)^2). I hope it will help you to calculate K-mean further.

Comment: The earth is round, it is necessary to include in the geographical distance. I am currently trying out different similarity functions. How to weighted time (milliseconds) and the geographical distance (kilometers) ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Units doesn't matter you can use meter or kilometer for distance for time milliseconds or seconds. But it is necessary to use consistent unit. The centroid you will get will be the same unit you are using.

Comment: i implement more variants of cores. this in the ref. paper below give the best results.